# Redirect 301 Not working the way I intended it to!

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Trying to get a simple 301 redirect with htaccess using this code:
    Redirect 301 /cat/radiator-cages/product/radiator-support-cage/ http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/

The results are sending me to
http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/?page=cat/radiator-cages/product/radiator-support-cage

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

--Update--

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]

Redirect 301 /cat/radiator-cages/product/radiator-support-cage/ http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/
```

Comment: Do you have other rules in the .htaccess file that could be producing this error? Such as a RewriteRule

Comment: @Ryan Matthews   I updated the original message with additional rules I have in my htaccess

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying to use the Redirect 301 statement first.

Your htaccess should then look somthing like this

```
    Redirect 301 /cat/radiator-cages/product/radiator-support-cage/ http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]
```

Edit:

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC] 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^/cat/radiator-cages/product/radiator-support-cage/$ http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/ [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]
```

http://www.gerronmulder.com/common-seo-rewrite-rules-for-apache-using-htaccess/

Comment: Also to test if the redirect is working remove the rewrite rules and see if it works.  Don't forget to clear your cache as well (firefox has this problem sometimes I noticed)

Comment: @Ryan Matthews,  Actually, I turned off the rewrite rules, and it did work. So now what do I do?

Comment: Does it work if you just have the first 3 lines under the redirect but dot the rewrite rule for product?

Comment: @Ryan Matthews , Yeah I commented out those 3 lines under the Redirect, and it worked. Thanks for the help btw. I really appreciate it.

Comment: What if it has everything but this line  RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/$ /index.php?page=product&parent_url=$1&product=$2 [L,NC]

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I it redirects to my 404 page with the rewrite rules not set, so if I turn off the 404, it does work.

Comment: Okay, I did try the edit you suggested. If I leave in the / [R=301,L]   I get an Internal Server Error throughout the entire site, if I remove the [R=301,L], it doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: I think you should be able to get it from that last edit. You may have to play around with it a bit. Possibly remove the http from it. But something along those lines should work.  If I wasn't at work I would test it out but I can't do that right now.

Comment: I will try and play around with it, see if I can come up with anything. Thanks for your help. LOL, check in here with me later just in case, if I figure it out I will post up my fix. Where you from in Michigan?

Comment: Yep, the east side of MI. Good Luck.

Comment: Well, I guess my best option right now is to use PHP's

    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");  with a
    header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/product/radiator-cages/custom-radiator-support-cage/");

Comment: Yeah I know, maybe one day I will understand more about htaccess lol. Is there any downsides to using php vs htaccess?

Comment: I guess php is the downfall as it has to run the string which increases load time, but in a month or two, I guess I can delete it the redirects.inc.php file, as the search engines will be updated.

Comment: Yea the downfall is that it will take a fraction of a second more. Usually a month should be good to leave the redirects there. Just check the search engines after a month and see what they have linked for your site.